# What is the best way to find HTML element

Tags: javascript

1. `var ele = document.getElementById("intro");`
2. `var ele = document.getElementByClassName("className");`
3. `var ele = document.getElementByTagName('p');`
4. `var x = document.querySelector("p.intro");`

What is the best way to select HTML element in JavaScript.

Comment: These match four completely different things and even return different type of data. It's impossible to say which is "best" without defining what you're actually looking for. Even then, as long as you match the correct element, the difference is negligible.

Comment: i want to know the best way to find the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am A Lazy Coder..
I Like To Use `document.querySelector()` To get An HTML Element.

Or If Someone Is Tooooo Lazy, Just Define a function:

```
function GetEl(el){
document.querySelector("#" + el);
}
```

Note: (In Actual Code Editors It Is Easy Peasy.. Just Start Typing and get a suggestion and hit enter)

If you are using a text editor: This will make your life easier..
.. Don't Mind If Your Code's length increased..

Comment: * Based on Laziness

Comment: but `document.querySelector()` select all the query maches in the document for example i want to find a p tag  but there is also alot of p tag in the document but queryselector select all the p tag what shall i do

Comment: Use ```querySelectorAll()```
Will Return Node List.
Use ```.item(index)``` to return element